# Creating a HUD on top of another application with Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, cocoa, hud

Is it possible to create a HUD with Cocoa on top of a window from another application? For example, if I were to create a Poker HUD, which would display information about opponents on top of a Poker Client window, how would I implement it in OS X (with Cocoa?).

For example how would I recreate the following Windows program (PokerTracker HUD: displays a HUD on top of PokerStars)?

[image: For example the PokerTracker HUD]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, partly because you're using Windows terminology (non-owned) that means nothing to Mac programmers.  Also, is the Poker Client a program that you own the source code to, or not?

Comment: I read the question twice.  I'm not sure what 'not owned' means, either.  I developed Windows applications till two and a half years ago, though.

Comment: @JWWalker I updated the question. With non-owned I meant that I simply didn't own the source code of that application/process/window. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: "PokerTracker" has a Mac version, so the answer is "yes it's possible", I guess. As for how to do it, it's interesting but way too broad as a question for SO.

Comment: @EricD.  I think the question is quite vague, but not too broad. The HUD widgets are not `NSWindow` elements, but what are they? The placement of the HUD is done typically through screenshots in combination with OCR and are vector-based and thus respond on resizing the Poker Client Window. But none of that I'm interested in, I'd just like to know how to draw those elements (eq. which Cocoa class is used).

Comment: Then edit your question and include all these new interesting details and then more, it will make a much more answerable question. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but I think the HUD elements would be controls or views within an `NSWindow` set up as an overlay.  Here are some key steps to configure it:

```
[myWindow setOpaque: NO];
[myWindow setBackgroundColor: [NSColor clearColor]];
[myWindow setLevel: NSStatusWindowLevel];
```

And then you'd need to track which app is frontmost, so that your overlay would only be visible when the target app is in front.  I think you could do this by finding the `NSRunningApplication` for the target app and then key-value-observing its `active` property.